# Capture and log to disk syslog remotely

Tags: windows, windows-xp, logging, tomato, syslogd

I have a Windows XP machine. On this machine, I would like to view data sent by my Tomato router, which is running syslogd, which I can configure to send out syslog data instead of logging internally. I know of some Linux utilities to do this, but I need to be able to capture the log being sent on Windows as well. Does anyone know of a suitable program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A google search for [windows syslog server](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=windows+syslog+server) returns lots of likely looking results.  It looks like 3Com has a [free one](http://support.3com.com/software/utilities_for_windows_32_bit.htm).

Comment: That's odd, I googled last night and didn't find any free ones. Guess my searching prowess must be getting on a bit. Thanks, I will test that now. :)

Comment: Seems to not work on Windows XP, which I guess is because it was made before it reached RTM. Will try some others in that google.

Comment: If nothing else works, you could probably run syslogd under [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).